# Argument in bash script duplicates output

Tags: linux, bash

i wrote a Bash shell script which prints out information about file or directory, provided in argument,
but something went wrong, and if i put dir in argument, it does not show me the list of files
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#!/bin/bash
for path in $1*
do
if [ -d $1 ]
then
        echo "File: '$1'"
        echo "Type: `stat -c%F $1`"
        echo "Permissions: (`stat -c%a/%A $1`)"
        echo "-----------"
elif [ -f $1 ]
then
        echo "File: '$1'"
        echo "Type: `stat -c%F $1`"
        echo "Permissions: (`stat -c%a/%A $1`)"
        echo "-----------"
fi
done
```

Comment: Здесь вопросы нужно задавать на русском языке.

Comment: привык читать stackoverflow на английском. буду иметь ввиду

Comment: 1. переведите, пожулуйста, текст вопроса (и ответа) на русский язык. 2. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Answer

```
#!/bin/bash
for path in $1*
do
if [ -d $path ]
then
        echo "File: '$path'"
        echo "Type: `stat -c%F $path`"
        echo "Permissions: (`stat -c%a/%A $path`)"
        echo "-----------"
elif [ -f $path ]
then
        echo "File: '$path'"
        echo "Type: `stat -c%F $path`"
        echo "Permissions: (`stat -c%a/%A $path`)"
        echo "-----------"
fi
done
```

Comment: По-хорошему надо один раз вызывать `stat`, а потом парсить его вывод.